# google drive file download bytes from offset to length

Tags: java, google-drive-api, google-api-java-client

Does any  method exist to partially download a file from `google-drive` using **offset** and **length**.

I want to download the `bytes` of the file from `offset` to `offset+length` .

I just want to know if there exists any method in `google-drive-api` in `Java`.

Comment: Please Tag Carefully ! The more care you tagging the more attention you get.

Answer (score 1):

You can specify required bytes in standard `Range` HTTP Header to download partial file. You can read more in the Google Drive API documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/manage-downloads#partial_download).

```
Range: bytes=500-999
```

Comment: Thank u. Can u please explain through java api

Answer (score 0):

You can use [InputStream](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get#examples) provided by Google Drive API. Example is clear enough

Then use `read(buffer, offset, length)`